# Map SharePoint Sub Sites into Separate Domains

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to map the SharePoint sub sites into separate domains.What is the procedure on doing it in SharePoint 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afarid that it is not possible to map seperate domain for Subsites. Lowest level you can isolate is upto WebApplication. That too you need to use FBA Claims based Authentication to get a web application running with two domain.

Comment: When I researched further on this topic I have found out there's a solution at site collection level. Refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

Comment: Well, still Isolation is at WebAppp / Site Collection level not at the subsite level.

Answer (score 0):

Later on I have found out that SharePoint Server 2010 supports host-named site collections as an alternative to creating individual Web applications.
Refer : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

Also, there's a farm solution @codeplex that creates host-header site collections on Central Admin with SharePoint 2010, out of the box. 
officetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/42507